# Finding $m$ so that the rank of the matrix is even

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Find $m$ so that the rank of the matrix is ​​even $$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 3& 1& m& 1\\ 1&2 &2&m+1\\3& 1& 1&0\\ 6&6&1&8 \end{pmatrix} . $$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The first minor is non-zero, so the rank is at least 2. The next possibility is 4, which is connected with singularity of the matrix $A$. It depends on certain quadratic equation.